# body has been altered failure on DKIM validation

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

I'm using PHPMailer to send mails and like to append a DKIM-signature to mails. I had problems before I applied [this patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmailer/bugs/403/). Now I'm able to send a successfull signed message to isnotspam.com.

I have successfully signed a message with less than 1500 characters in the body. If increase the character count (even with simple a's) The signature fails.

I've correctly set up a TXT domain record.

I guess it's because of the email's body cause if I use [this service](http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim/) I always get a "wrong body hash" error.

Signature in the email header looks like this one:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; l=641; s=mymail;
    t=1354285494; c=relaxed/simple;
    h=From:To:Subject;
    d=revaxarts.com;
    z=From:=20"WP=203.4"=20<info@rvaxarts.com>
    |To:=test@rvaxarts.com
    |Subject:=20DKIM=20Test;
    bh=Sx1Rj3c65v2Hk0fmg2j5XNIDi14=;
    b=n4OGAwl3i[...]AOkfUglp6iiYZ6B2M3ZKlGW5gDfE=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem here with a Perl script and wrong body hash.

I used `\n` for newline (example end of header line).
But you have to use `\r\n`. This solved it for me!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to ArtemGr for the comment and url to the following information (copied from http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/223780 to prevent link rot):

A likely cause of breakage is that the sending application generates
email that is incompatible with RFC 5322 or RFC 5321 in some respect.

- Lines longer than 990.

  The Postfix SMTP client keeps the line length below the SMTP
  protocol limit of 1000 bytes including . Since this change
  happens after signing, it will definitely break DKIM signatures.

  To avoid long-line curruption problems send mail in quoted-printable
  or base64 encoding, with lines of at most 80 characters long.
- Malformed line endings.

  SMTP requires  line endings, and does not allow  or
   characters in any other context.

  The Postfix sendmail commands expects UNIX-style `<LF>` [line-feed] line endings.
  It will also accept lines ending in `<CR><LF>` [carriage-return line-feed] but you can't use
  mixed line ending styles in the same message.

And so on. If you want to ensure that DKIM signatures survive, you
need to send email that is within the protocol specs of RFC 5322 or RFC 5321;

Comment: Also, if the email body has very long lines (when all `\r?\n` are replaced with `<br/>` for example) the server will split them (cf. http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/223780).

Answer (score 0):

My case was unicode apostrophe and hypen chars. After replacing them with ascii ones, the DKIM validation is passed.